# Show break in axis in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've defined the following axis

```
\draw[->,thick,black!70] (0,1,0) -- (1,1,0) node[right] {X};
```

However I'd like to display some breaks say at `0.25` and `0.75`. How would one do this?

Comment: How should those breaks look like? Can you provide an image of the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

No information was provided about how to represent the breaks, so I presebt two options. The first one, using the `pos` key to place two white-filled nodes (instead of empty labels for the nodes you could use any desired symbol to indicate the breaks):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->,thick,black!70] (0,1,0) -- (1,1,0) node[right] {$X$} node[pos=0.25,fill=white,inner xsep=2pt] {} node[pos=0.75,fill=white,inner xsep=2pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, commonly used to represent those breaks, is to drawn a pair of diagonal segments; this can be accomplished with a style using decorations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\def\MarkLt{4pt}
\def\MarkSep{2pt}

\tikzset{
  TwoMarks/.style={
    postaction={decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position #1 with
          {
              \begin{scope}[xslant=0.2]
              \draw[line width=\MarkSep,white,-] (0pt,-\MarkLt) -- (0pt,\MarkLt) ;
              \draw[-] (-0.5*\MarkSep,-\MarkLt) -- (-0.5*\MarkSep,\MarkLt) ;
              \draw[-] (0.5*\MarkSep,-\MarkLt) -- (0.5*\MarkSep,\MarkLt) ;
              \end{scope}
          }
       }
    }
  },
  TwoMarks/.default={0.5},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->,thick,black!70,TwoMarks=0.25,TwoMarks=0.75] (0,1,0) -- (1,1,0) node[right] {$X$}; \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]